# Joomla error for JPATH_BASE in site migiration

Tags: php, joomla

My friend has asked me to take a look at his Joomla site to make some change; However I have never used Joomla so i'm currently learning from the documentation.

When I moved his site over to my server to take a look without disturbing his site.

I have made the changed in the configuration file to suit the servers config.

However I'm getting the following error:

ME/MYSITE/WWW/TEMPLATES/SHAPER_VOCAL/LESS/MASTER.LESS

I can not find ME/MYSITE/WWW/ to change to my own servers path. 
I have even done a Dreamweaver entire site search in the source code for ME/MYSITE/WWW/ however I'm have no luck.

Is it possible it is set somewhere in the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JPATH_BASE isn't defined with a hardcoded path in the code.
You can redefine it anyway in your index.php like this :

```
define('JPATH_BASE', __DIR__);
```